# define db value while creating connection with redis into nginx.conf file while using Openresty

Tags: nginx, lua

I am using Redis with Django project which is running on nginx and i am creating connection by code

```
red = redis.Redis("localhost", port=6397, db=5, socket_timeout=2)
```

Now by using Openresty i am fetching cache data from Redis using lua into nginx.conf file i am able to create connection

```
local redis = require "resty.redis"
local red = redis:new()
red:set_timeout(1000) -- 1 second
local ok, err = red:connect("10.0.0.161", 6379)
```

Here in nginx.conf file i am not able to understand how can define db value .
I tried `local ok, err = red:connect("10.0.0.161", 6379, {db=5)` but it is not working .
Please help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use select once connected:

```
red:select(5)
```